Ansible ini_file append an option instead of replace
This is in reference to ansible-collections/community.zabbix Issue #1294 "RHEL9 zabbix-agent package upgrade fails when installed with community.zabbix.zabbix_agent".
Basic ask is to disable the zabbix binary within the epel.repo because of version conflicts. My problem is
How do I add zabbix within the epel section of the epel.repo file, and still preserve any already existing exclusions?
I could slurp the file first, and use a chain of other commands to see if there is an existing line there already and then extract the values so that I can append them to the ini_file command but that seams really complicated and convoluted.
Would love any suggestions.

Have you considered using ansible.builtin.yum_repository or ansible.builtin.blockinfile

I've considered the yum_repo module, but in order to use it, I would have to specify the source which means I would still have to read the existing file and extract the source (same problem I currently have).  I think the same would be true with blockinfile as well.  Unfortunately if this was my own role for my own deployment and I controlled everything it would be easy but given the fact this is for the community collection, I don't get to make any assumptions.  Thanks though.

How about What is the proper way to read an option in INI-file on remote node with Ansible?


How do I add zabbix within the epel section of the epel.repo file, and still preserve any already existing exclusions?

Based on What is the proper way to read an option in INI-file on Remote Node with Ansible?, after creating a symlink and which could be done in a file task too
ln -s /home/ansible_user/test/example.repo /etc/ansible/facts.d/custom_soft.fact
ls -l /etc/ansible/facts.d/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  36 Jul 16 05:00 custom_soft.fact -> /home/ansible_user/test/example.repo

a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: ansible_local

  - name: Make sure key value is in INI file
    ini_file:
      path: example.repo
      section: epel
      option: "excludepkgs"
      value: "{% if ansible_local.custom_soft.epel.excludepkgs is defined %}{{ ansible_local.custom_soft.epel.excludepkgs }},{% endif %}zabbix*"

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  ansible_local:
    custom_soft:
      epel:
        enabled: '1'
        excludepkgs: example
        failovermethod: priority
        gpgcheck: '1'
        gpgkey: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
        mirrorlist: http://mirrors.example.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-9&arch=$basearch
        name: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - $basearch

TASK [Make sure key value is in INI file] ******************************************
changed: [localhost]

with file content of
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.example.org/pub/epel/9/$basearch
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.example.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-9&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
excludepkgs = example,zabbix*

Please take note to make the task fully idempotent you'll need to implement little more logic in order to avoid adding the value zabbix multiple times.

I could slurp the file first, and use a chain of other commands to see if there is an existing line there already and then extract the values so that I can append them to the ini_file command ...

By utilizing Custom Facts one can avoid slurp or fetch, lots of tasks like set_fact, as well other more complex IF THEN ELSE constructs.

Its an interesting idea but it requires that I add files and directories to the target host that are only needed in order to make Ansible work which doesn't seem particularly good.  Again, thank you for the suggestion though.

But that's the fact for ANY module and task. Ansible transfer it as Python code to the Remote Node, even if only temporary. See Ansible module architecture. Such could be done for the symlink too, one need only to clean it up after.

If that is already too much, a Custom Module can easily be written. For something like ini_remote, How to read and write INI file with Python3?
